# Loading Records from a child table with a node.js API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux

Ok,

I'm pretty new to node.js and the whole concept of callback functions, and I've been racking my brain trying to figure this out.  Maybe some of you guys/gals can help.

So the basic setup is that I have a React/Redux app on the front-end that uses an API as a data source.  On the front, I want to load some number of products at once and load all of their images, then I have a Product component that shows a single product, and would show an image gallery (which is why I need all the product images at once)

I'm trying to write an API the when I request http://myapi.com/randomproducts/ which will return an indicated number of random products from a MySQL database.  That part I have.  Here's the part that is throwing me... each product that I return in this array of products has an unknown of images associated with it.  I want to load those at the same time such that my what I return looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    product_id: 0,
    product_name: "my cool product",
    product_desc: "desc of my cool product",
    price: 10.00,
    product_images: [
          {
            product_image_id: 10,
            product_image:  "img1.jpg",
          },
          {
            product_image_id: 11,
            product_image:  "img2.jpg",
          },
          {
            product_image_id: 12,
            product_image:  "img3.jpg",
          }
    ]
  },
  {
    product_id: 2,
    product_name: "my other cool product",
    product_desc: "desc of my other cool product",
    price: 20.00,
    product_images: [
          {
            product_image_id: 13,
            product_image:  "img21.jpg",
          },
          {
            product_image_id: 14,
            product_image:  "img22.jpg",
          },
          {
            product_image_id: 15,
            product_image:  "img23.jpg",
          }
    ]
  },

]
```

*... and so on.*

So it's clear that there's a parent-child relationship between **products** (the parent table) and **product_images** (the child table).  Unfortunately, I have had no success creating an API function that will return an array of images which also has it's array of associated images.  The ultimate goal is that I want to load multiple products and their associated images at once in one single API call, instead of getting the the products, then getting the images.

Here's a snapshot of the database tables:

[CLICK HERE TO VIEW DATABASE TABLES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnVhn.jpg)

Here is the code that I have:

## 1. THE ROUTE

**Send a text/json body to this route.  It accepts a userId and a number of products to return:**

```
app.route('/multiplerandomproducts/')
.post(products.get_multiple_random_products);

post body:  {user_id: <num>, product_count: <num>}
```

## 2. GETTING MY PRODUCTS

**In my ProductsController.js Controller, I have the following:**

```
exports.get_multiple_random_products = function(req,res) {
  var postData = new Product(req.body);
  Product.getMultipleRandomProducts(postData.data, function(err,products) {
    if(err) {
      res.send(err); 
    } else {
      res.json(products);
    }
  });
}
```

**In my Products.js Model, I have the following:**

```
// get a random product for the userId
Product.getMultipleRandomProducts = function getMultipleRandomProducts(postData, result) {
    var userId = postData.user_id;
    var productCount = postData.product_count;

    var sqlStr = "SELECT DISTINCT a.* FROM product a "
    + " INNER JOIN product_category b ON b.product_id = a.product_id "
    + " INNER JOIN user_category c ON c.category_id = b.category_id "
    + " WHERE c.user_id= ? "

    // get only products that the user hasn"t seen before
    if(process.env.APP_HIDESEENPRODS === "1") {
        sqlStr += " AND a.product_id NOT IN (SELECT c.product_id from seen_product c WHERE c.user_id = ?)";
    }

    sqlStr += " ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ?";

    sql.query(sqlStr, [userId, userId, productCount], function(err, res) {
        if(err) {
            result(err, null);
        } else {
            // hide from the use if this flag is set in the app
            if(!process.env.APP_HIDESEENPRODS === "1") {
                insertUserSeenProduct(userId, res[0].product_id);
            }
            result(null,res);
        }
    });
}
```

**I also have a ProductImages.js model, which as a method to get Images for a particular product, which looks like this:**

```
ProductImage.getAllProductImages = function getAllProductImages(productId, result) {
        sql.query("Select * from product_image WHERE product_id = ? ", productId, function (err, res) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log("error: ", err);
                    result(null, err);
                }
                else {
                    result(null, res);
                }
            });   
    };
```

## What I've tried:

So this is the version of my function that I've tried to implement.  When I indicate that I want three records, I get an object with three null values, i.e., [null,null,null].  I think I'm close, just not seeing what I'm doing wrong....

```
Product.getMultipleRandomProducts = function getMultipleRandomProducts(postData, result) {
    var userId = postData.user_id;
    var productCount = postData.product_count;

    var sqlStr = "SELECT DISTINCT a.* FROM product a "
    + " INNER JOIN product_category b ON b.product_id = a.product_id "
    + " INNER JOIN user_category c ON c.category_id = b.category_id "
    + " WHERE c.user_id= ? "

    // get only products that the user hasn"t seen before
    if(process.env.APP_HIDESEENPRODS === "1") {
        sqlStr += " AND a.product_id NOT IN (SELECT c.product_id from seen_product c WHERE c.user_id = ?)";
    }

    sqlStr += " ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ?";

    sql.query(sqlStr, [userId, userId, productCount], function(err, res) {
        if(err) {
            result(err, null);
        } else {
            // hide from the use if this flag is set in the app
            if(!process.env.APP_HIDESEENPRODS === "1") {
                insertUserSeenProduct(userId, res[0].product_id);
            }
            result(null, res.map((item) => {
                sql.query("Select * from product_image WHERE product_id = ? ", item.product_id, function (err, res2) {
                    if(err) {
                        console.log("error: ", err);
                        result(null, err);
                    }
                    else {
                        item.product_images = res2;
                    }
                });                  
            }));
        }

    });
}
```

## The Problem that I'm running into:

So, I've tried to simply iterate through the returned array of products that I get back within  and get the product images, which would work fine if this wasn't asynchronous.  *But when I try this, I return an object with three products (if I ask for three) but only one (the first) of those products has it's images assigned to it.*

In summary, I want to return a single object that looks something like:

- Product

  - image
  - image
  - image
- Product

  - image
  - image
  - image
- Product

  - image
  - image
  - image

So, can someone please, PLEASE tell me how I can do this?  I'm still trying to wrap my head around callback functions and I'm about to have a brain aneurysm!

## Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Because the images of each product were fetch individually, the expected result is what your getting now. In fact, if you use a server (not local), chances are no images return to any of the products.

Use `async/await` and `promisify` your function to fetch the production images:

```
sql.query(sqlStr, [userId, userId, productCount], async function(err, res) {
    if(err) {
        result(err, null);
    } else {
        // hide from the use if this flag is set in the app
        if(!process.env.APP_HIDESEENPRODS === "1") {
            insertUserSeenProduct(userId, res[0].product_id);
        }

        // Get the list of images thru promisify
        const getImages = function(item) {
            return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
                sql.query("Select * from product_image WHERE product_id = ? ", item.product_id, function (err, res2) {
                    if(err) {
                        console.log("error: ", err);
                        reject(result(null, err));
                    }
                    else {
                        item.product_images = res2;

                        resolve(item);
                    }
                });
            });
        };

        let products = [];

        const returnFalse = () => false;

        for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++ ) {
            let product = await getImages(res[i]).catch(returnFalse);

            if (product) {
                products.push(product);
            }
        }

        result( null, products);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey Irene!  Thanks for the feedback.  That looks "promising" (pun intended).  However, when I ran this, what I got back was an array of three empty objects, like this...  [
    {},
    {},
    {}
]   .... any thoughts?  Thanks again!

Comment: Edited my response and replace it with the good old passion for loop -:

Comment: YAAAAYYY!!!  That worked!  I'm not worthy lol.  Thanks for that, you're my new hero!